# Magento grid column position

Tags: php, magento

I'm editing the order grid by adding custom columns like this

```
$this->addColumn('pagamenti', array(
  'header'    => 'Paymentsource',
  'width'=>'50px',
  'align'     =>'left',
  'type'    => 'text',
  'renderer' => 'Blablabla_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_lol'
));
```

but every column is positioned on the far right of the table, no matter where I call addColumns.

Is there a way to force the position?

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can probably use the `addColumnAfter` function.

```
$this->addColumnAfter('pagamenti', array(
  'header'    => 'Paymentsource',
  'width'=>'50px',
  'align'     =>'left',
  'type'    => 'text',
  'renderer' => 'Blablabla_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_lol'
), 'id_of_column_to_be_after');
```

Comment: watch out, the order of calling this before the parent may be important, see the answer of Praful Rajput

Answer (score 15):

If you've ever looked at the [`_prepareColumns`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Adminhtml/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.html#_prepareColumns) method that you're overriding you'll see that it calls [`sortColumnsByOrder`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Adminhtml/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.html#sortColumnsByOrder). So if you're adding a column after this point (perhaps with an event) you'll need to do something like:

```
$this->addColumnsOrder('pagamenti', 'real_order_id')
    ->sortColumnsByOrder();
```

Comment: This is a very worthy tip. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

If you called  **parent::_prepareColumns();** before  **$this->addColumn()** or **$this->addColumnAfter()** then your new column always been display at last position. So you may adjust the place of **parent::_prepareColumns();** statement as per your requirement.

```
$this->addColumnAfter('barcode', array(
            'header'           => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Barcode'),
            'align'            => 'left',
            'index' => 'barcode',
            'width' => '200px',

        ),'real_order_id');

        parent::_prepareColumns();
```

Here, Barcode column will be shown just after **Order Id #** column. If you put **parent::_prepareColumns();** before **$this->addColumnAfter** then it will not display just after Order ID # column.  It will display at last only.

Comment: This answer will only result in the new columns being added to the very first or very last positions in the list.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have pointed out, you can utilize the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::addColumnAfter` method to accomplish this.

However what (most of) the other answers fail to mention is that **you must explicitly call `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::sortColumnsByOrder` in order for the columns to be reordered**.

The `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::sortColumnsByOrder` method is called exclusively by the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns` method as follows:

```
/// app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php line 557
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
    return $this;
}
```

This means that your derived class will have to do the same in order to re-sort the columns based upon your new ordering.  For example:

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {

    /// Let the parent add some columns
    /// Mage_Eav_Block_Adminhtml_Attribute_Grid_Abstract does add some
    parent::_prepareColumns();

    /// Add some new columns
    $this->addColumnAfter('sort_order', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Sort Order'),
        'sortable' => true,
        'index' => 'sort_order'
    ), 'frontend_label');

    $this->addColumnAfter('attribute_group_name', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Attribute Group'),
        'sortable' => true,
        'index' => 'attribute_group_name'), 'sort_order');

    /// ! IMPORTANT ! Re-sort the columns with the new additions
    $this->sortColumnsByOrder();
    return $this;
}
```